# My screen is flickering purple and cyan

Tags: macbook-pro

My screen has a bunch of purple and cyan flickering bars on it. Does anyone know if there is a fix for this? I have tried resetting my nvram. I closed my lip for 15 minutes and then when I opened it, these lines appeared. I also run a diagnostics, but there were no hardware issues found.

[image: my screen]

Comment: Apple offers FREE diagnosis and cost estimate. Start in Safe mode (no graphics just text)

Comment: @Ruskes You get graphics in Safe mode.  You may be thinking of Single user Mode.

Comment: Try a safe boot.
    Shutdown your machine.  Hold down the shift key.  Poweron.  The boot up will take longer than normal because the filesystem on the startup drive is being checked and repaired as needed.   All about safe mode including what features and apps safe boot leaves out.  Safe boot uses a software driver instead of using your machines video hardware.
      http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455

Comment: I have the same problem, in small angle it work good. After diagnostics me said that its cable (flexgate) problem and fix that they can only change monitor screen , price between 600-700$. @rob how you fix this problem???

Comment: @RomanSlezenko Sorry, only just saw this comment. For people wanted to know how I fixed this problem, I had to get this fixed in the apple store. I hope you sorted your screen

Comment: Similar problem here: https://superuser.com/questions/1708164/choppy-display-on-a-mid-2015-macbook-pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say that looks an awful lot like a hardware error.

It could be a bad video card, issues with the screen itself or the connection between the two (cables, connectors, etc.).

If you boot into recovery mode is the issue still present? That would rule out an issue with your OS if it is still there.

My advice, seek the help of a qualified Apple tech. Either at an Apple store or a good 3rd-party Apple certified repair center.